# Select List of some object property from Double level object list

Tags: c#, linq

I have double level list of some object. I want to get list of some property values based on some condition.

for ex

i have following Class

```
public class Demo
{
    public string Prop1 {get; set;}
    public string Prop2 {get; set;}
}
```

I have created the double list of above class object

```
List<List<Demo>> lst = new List<List<Demo>>();

List<Demo> lstdemo1 = new List<Demo>
lstdemo1.Add(new Demo(){Prop1 = "1", Prop2="abc"});
lstdemo1.Add(new Demo(){Prop1 = "2", Prop2="pqr"});

List<Demo> lstdemo2 = new List<Demo>
lstdemo2.Add(new Demo(){Prop1 = "1", Prop2="mno"});
lstdemo2.Add(new Demo(){Prop1 = "2", Prop2="xyz"});

lst.Add(lstdemo1);
lst.Add(lstdemo2);
```

Now i want get List which have Prop2 values depends to Prop1 value
For ex : I want get list of Prop2 where Prop1 is equal to "1"

I want following output
`List<string>` lstoutput
which contains

> "abc","mno"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method is to make use of LINQ's `SelectMany` to flatten the list. Accomplish this using two `from` clauses in query syntax:

```
var query = from x in lst
            from y in x
            where y.Prop1.Equals("1")
            select y.Prop2;
```

Or, by calling `SelectMany` in method syntax:

```
var query = lst.SelectMany(x => x.Where(y => y.Prop1.Equals("1"))
                                 .Select(y => y.Prop2));
```

Comment: Not a problem. If you're new to LINQ don't forget to call ToList() on your result to actually execute the query, especially if you are going to enumerate through the list more than once.

Answer (score 2):

Use [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var result = lst.SelectMany(o => o).Where(o => o.Prop1 == "1").Select(o => o.Prop2).ToList();
```